# Possible to set Azure load balancing affinity method for App Services?

Tags: azure

I know that you can set the type of load balancer affinity used for Azure VM's, as described here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-distribution-mode/

Is it possible to do the same with Azure App Services (formerly websites)? Basically, I want to use the "none" algorithm because the load testing I'm doing is all coming from the same IP. I can see from logging that all requests end up being routed to the same instance, which is not particularly useful for a load test. :)

Answer (score 1):

Affinity is On by default which means the load balancer will keep the user to the same instance during his session. All you have to do is switch it off.

[image: App Settings]

Comment: I'm aware of that... but that isn't what I was asking. I can observe that it still sticks to the same instance, presumably based on IP. If app services work like the affinity in the above link, then by default they'll stick via IP.

Comment: After shutting off affinity, make sure to clear the browser's cookies and storage for the Url.